# VMware vCenter Web Client UI and data service tweaking

Tags: java, swing, apache-flex, sdk, flex4.5

Hi am trying to tweak the vcenter web ui client interface , i tried creating a new extension point using web client SDK , Is there any way to change the web client UI without adding a extension point , I want to include a new input field in ui while provisioning the storage datastore and tweak in data service layer

Comment: *"vcenter web ui client interface"*  Is it written in Java?  What is it (link to it)?

Comment: Yes business logic layer in Java spring , they are using FLEX for UI Frinje framework

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VSP510-WEBCLIENTSDK-510&productId=285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can't edit existing pages without creating an extension points, to edit the existing pages like adding new columns to tables you can extend the list view section.

For more details refer the [**Extending vSphere Object List Views Section**](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wcsdk.pg.doc/ListExtensions_Chapter.12.1.html) in vSphere web client SDK Programming Guide.

Answer (score 2):

Having had a look at the [Customizing the vSphere Client](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/vcplugin/) guide, I think what you intend to do could be possible by editing the Web UI plugin internals, and that is modifying its [source code](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=229&downloadGroup=VCO_POWERSHELL_PLUGIN_1.0).

You should check the [Orchestrator documentation](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/orchestrator_pubs.html) to see if what you intend to do can be done without modifying the source code. For example, I read in [this guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r41/vsp_41_web_access.pdf) you can customize what the user can do by customizing the URL you use for accessing the Web Client.